# How to implement a try catch wrapper in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, macros

I'm trying to implement a try catch wrapper with syntax like this:

```
TRY_CATCH{
    task1();
    task2();
    task3();
}
```

If either task fails, the exception will be caught and handled.

I was doing something like this:

```
#define TRY_CATCH_EXPR(...)                                       \
{                                                                 \
    try                                                           \
    {                                                             \
        __VA_ARGS__                                               \
    }                                                             \
    catch (std::exception & err)                                  \
    {                                                             \
        // do sth.                                                \
    }                                                             \
    catch (...)                                                   \
    {                                                             \
        // do sth.                                                \
    }                                                             \
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
TRY_CATCH_EXPR(
    printf("hello world!\n");
);
```

It works fine for me for now.

So my question is:

1. What's the potential danger with this macro
2. Is it possible to make the "{}" syntax work, rather then wrapping the expression with "();"?

**Edit:**
I only use the wrapper when the exception is predictable and can be handled smoothly with the "do sth.", for the first question, I am more concerned about the **VA_ARGS** part, is there any case where it won't work as intended?

Also, my primary goal is to implement a macro with syntax like this:

```
MACRO{
    // multiple lines of expressions
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Whether this is a good idea or not will largely depend on what `// do sth.` does. Silently catching exceptions (and ignoring them) is dangerous and discouraged, however you do it.

Comment: There is plenty of information about the dangers of macros in general.   All such dangers apply to your macro as much as any other.

Comment: @PMF I use this wrapper only when I know for sure that the possible exception is not important and can be ignored. I am more concerned about the "__VA_ARGS__" part, is there any case, it won't work as intended?

Comment: Why do you need this? It looks like you are annoyed by the number of thrown exceptions. I personally don’t like this - it hides behavior.

Comment: @zdf In many cases, the exception is not important, like reading a non-existent member in a Json object, I can just ignore the it. And I only use it in cases where the exception is predictable and unimportant. I am more curious about how to make the {} syntax work.

Comment: Also, a macro to simplify the writing of `try`/`catch` code is a code smell that indicates you're over-using `try`/`catch` (or you're over-reliant on throwing exceptions). Exceptions should be thrown sparingly (i.e.  only for critical problems that cannot be fixed in code that detects the concern AND where, if the cause is not fixed, execution should stop).  They should only need to be caught in a few places (e.g.  in `main()`, where exceptions will all eventually propagate if not caught) AND all other code should be written so it doesn't break due to functions it calls throwing exceptions.

Comment: You should avoid doing code like this, hiding things has a tendency of not aging well and also makes debugging harder.   Instead use a template as somebody suggested or redesign so you do not have to handle so many exceptions.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the suggestion. But jsoncpp throws a lot when accessing non-existent fields or parsing ill-formated json file. I thought it would be convenient to wrap those operations(like reading multiple members in the json object) with a simple try-catch wrapper, since the possible exception usually wouldn't be important, and it saves me a lot of time.

Comment: @TheoMars   My point is that you shouldn't be trying to individually wrap every single function call that may throw.    Or find a better json library that doesn't indiscriminately throw exceptions (throwing exceptions should be an exceptional occurrence - a parsing error is not a particularly exceptional occurrence).

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it with no macros, and therefore no potential complications with `__VA_ARGS__` and other preprocessor-related dangers.

```
// in some header
template <typename F> void try_catch(F&& f) {
    try { f(); }
    catch (std::exception & err) { /* ... */ }
    catch (...) { /* ... */ }
}

try_catch ([&](){ 
   task1();
   task2();
   task3();
});
```

I don't think there is a way to do it with your desired syntax, macros or no macros.